# Is the image of a contractible space under a contraction contractible?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, contraction-operator

Is the image of a contractible space under a contraction contractible?

More specific to what I'm looking for: is the image of the unit ball $B_1(0)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ under a contraction mapping $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ still contractible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. For instance, the map 
\begin{align*}
F: \mathbb{R}^2 &\to \mathbb{R}^2 \\
(x,y) &\mapsto \frac{1}{4\pi}\left(\cos(2\pi x), \sin(2\pi x)\right)
\end{align*}
takes the unit ball to a circle, which is not contractible. That the map is a contraction can be seen by the derivative, or by noticing that it is the composition of the projection in the first coordinate with a walk on the circle with constant velocity equal to $1/2$. (This should make for a quick visualization that it is indeed a contraction.)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the smooth surjective exponential map, which is Lipschitz continuous $e: T_S S^n = \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow S^n$ ($S$ being the south pole).

Consider a large $M>0$ and a small $r > 0$ and define $F(x_1, \ldots, x_{n+1})=r \cdot e(Mx_1, \ldots, Mx_n) \in S^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

If $M$ is large enough, then $F(B_1(0))=rS^n$ for any $r$. If you choose then $r$ small enough, $F$ is a contraction, and the image of $B_1(0)$ is homeomorphic to $S^n$, which is not contractible.

Comment: What do you mean with the "smooth surjective exponential map"?

Comment: I don't think this is correct, since you can find two points arbitrary close in the original space, which map to the two ends of the sphere $S^n$. Unless you choose $r=0$, I think this is doesn't hold. If you choose $r=0$, the sphere is a point.

Comment: @YRI: no, if $\ell$ is the geodesic length from the north to the south, points of $\mathbb{R}^n$ mapped by $e$ to the north (resp. south) pole of $S^n$ have a norm which is an odd (resp. even) multiple of $\ell$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand. I think it is because I don't understand how the map $e$ is defined.

Comment: To define $e(x)$, you draw the geodesic (ie the circle going through the north and south pole, such that $x$ is tangent to the circle at $S$, in $S^n$. You run through this circle at speed $1$ and stop at time $|x|$ (starting from $S$ in direction $x$).

Comment: What do you mean with "$x$ is tangent to the circle at $S$, in $S^n$? What is $S$ exactly? how can a single point be tangent to something?

Comment: $S$ is the south pole of the sphere. I wrote this sentence poorly, the end should read as “$x$ is tangent to the circle at $S$) in $S^n$.

Answer (score -2):

The map $H_t(x)=tF(x), t\in [0,1]$ restricted to the unit ball defines a deformation retract of the unit ball to a point.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn’t tell anything about the contractibility of $F(B_1(0))$.

Comment: I do not fully understand your answer @TsemoAristide . Does this mean the answer is yes? What do you mean with "retract of the unit ball"? I'm not very knowledgeable on algebra I'm afraid...